# Laptop keyboard won't wakeup the device

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, suspend, bluetooth

I got an IdeaPad 710s recently and its been working great with Ubuntu 18 for the most part.

The issue I have is that I can't wakeup the device from sleep by pressing the keyboard, power button or trackpad. I can only wake it up using a USB or Bluetooth devices connected to it.

I've already added all the USB listed by `grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup` in `/etc/rc.local`. That got an USB mouse to be able to wakeup the laptop, but the internal devices since won't do it. A bluetooth mouse worked out of the box to wake up the laptop...

Any idea how I can retrieve the ACPI ID or similar of the internal keyboard/trackpad and how to set them as devices allowed to wakeup the laptop?